# Send mail in javax.mail without authentication

Tags: java, email, authentication, jakarta-mail

I am using javax.mail to send mails in Java.
Now that a part of the concept of my project changed I have to send a mail without authentication. I will have to change my createSession() method:

```
private void createSession() {
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", server);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });
}
```

It is rather obvious that I should change `mail.smtp.auth` to `false`, but what else should I change?

Comment: Do not add `user` and `password` to the `property` and pass `null` for `user` and `password` to `connect`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
private void createSession() {
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
     //Put below to false, if no https is needed
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", server);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    session = Session.getInstance(properties);
}
```

I think, this would suffice.

Comment: And of course it depends on your server being configured to allow you to send mail without authenticating first.  That might work fine within an intranet, otherwise it's an invitation to spam.

Comment: Still says `Authentication Required. Please contact support`

Comment: Authentication is a server policy. If the server requires authentication - you have to provide it!!

Comment: put properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false"); as well.It worked for this after this change.

Comment: This does not work if change mobile date, can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score -3):

```
private void createSession() {
  properties.put("mail.smtp.auth",false);
  properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.username","username(emailid")");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.password","password(mail password)");

  Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,null);

}
```

Comment: Pelase explain your answer.