# How to disable authentication for JavaMailSenderImp?

Tags: java, spring, email

This is the code I have:

```
private MailSender getMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        sender.setHost("mail");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        sender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);

        return sender;
    }
```

The host is ok. I still get the AuthenticationException.
Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: PLease share Context.xml file

Comment: See similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115732/send-mail-in-javax-mail-without-authentication.
If the solution suggested there does not work for you then check whether the mail server you are using is configured to allow connections without authentication.