# How to send email using Wildfly, where the SMTP doesn't need a password?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

I have the following problem: How do I send an email using `Wildfly` when the SMTP doesn't need a password?

I already succeeded doing this using `Glassfish`. But when I migrate to `Wildfly`, I don't know what parameter I need to pass.

This is my `Glassfish` configuration:

[image]

This is my `standalone.xml`:

```
<mail-session name="noreply" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/noreply" from="something@domainblablabla.com">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="blablabla-smtp" ssl="true" tls="false" username="something@domainblablabla.com"/>
</mail-session>

<outbound-socket-binding name="blablabla-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't found the setting in wildfly, but i edit the code following this answer.

[Send mail in javax.mail without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115732/send-mail-in-javax-mail-without-authentication)

this solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom-server in mail-session definition
where you can define whatever java mail properties you want.

example from some testcase

```
<mail-session name="custom" debug="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Custom">
        <custom-server name="smtp" username="username" password="password">
            <property name="host" value="mail.example.com"/>
        </custom-server>
        <custom-server name="pop3" outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-pop3">
            <property name="custom_prop" value="some-custom-prop-value"/>
            <property name="some.fully.qualified.property" value="fully-qualified-prop-name"/>
        </custom-server>
    </mail-session>
```