# How can send mail in java, nonlogin process

Tags: java

I have a requirement of sending the email with the attachment of a file. I found few online java code but that is through gmail/yahoo with login credentials. But I want to send it as anonymous instead of logging in.

Similar to what is available in oracle plsql UTIL_SMTP

Any body can help here!
Thanks inadvance

Comment: Do you have a mail account which you can use to send emails anonymously?

Answer (score 1):

Basic steps:

1. Have your server configured to allow you to send mail without authentication.
2. Use Java Mail API. Create a session using Java Mail API as described here in another SO question: [Send mail in javax.mail without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115732/send-mail-in-javax-mail-without-authentication)